# how to reshape into multi-level, multi-ordered wide data using dynamic column names

Tags: r, plyr, reshape

sorry if this has an obvious answer.  i'm trying to perform a reshape that has lots of stackoverflow answers when only one column gets used or when the column names can be hardcoded, but i need an answer that will work dynamically when the `ordered.cols` and `unique.cols` vectors are not set from the beginning

```
# these two sets of columns need to be dynamic
# they might be any two sets of columns!
ordered.cols <- c( 'cyl' , 'gear' )
unique.cols <- c( 'am' , 'vs' )
# neither of the above two character vectors will be known beforehand


# so here's the example starting data set
x <- mtcars[ , c( ordered.cols , unique.cols ) ]

# the desired output should have this many records:
unique( x[ , ordered.cols ] )
# but i'm unsure of the smartest way to add the additional columns that i want--


# for *each* unique level in *each* of the variables in
# `unique.cols` there should be one additional column added
# to the final output.  then, for that `ordered.cols` combination
# the cell should be populated with the value if it exists
# and NA otherwise
desired.output <-
    structure(list(cyl = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L), gear = c(3L, 
    4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L), am1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L), am2 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), vs1 = c(1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), vs2 = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 
    NA, NA)), .Names = c("cyl", "gear", "am1", "am2", "vs1", "vs2"
    ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))


desired.output
```

i don't really care if the new columns are named am1, am2, vs1, vs2, or something more convenient.  but if there are two distinct values of `am` in the data, there need to be two data-holding columns in the final output, one of which should be missing if that combination doesn't have the value.

```
# second example #
ordered.cols <- c( 'a' , 'b' )
unique.cols <- 'd'

# starting data set
y <-
    data.frame( 
        a = c( 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 ) , 
        b = c( 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 ) , 
        d = c( 'z' , 'y' , 'x' , 'x' ) 
    )

# the desired output here should have this many rows..
unique( y[ , ordered.cols ] )
# now the contents of all columns in `unique.cols`
# (which in this case is only column `d`)
# need to be appended as a widened data set

second.desired.output <-
    data.frame( 
        a = c( 1 , 1 , 2 ) ,
        b = c( 1 , 2 , 2 ) ,
        d1 = c( 'z' , 'x' , 'x' ) ,
        d2 = c( 'y' , NA , NA )
    )

second.desired.output
```

thanks!!!!!!

Comment: I would have called this reshaping to "wide", and I'm a bit unclear which columns are supposed to be known by name (or not) at the beginning.b Also there were 6 lines of data in 'x' that has cyl and gear = 4 with am= 1, so how does that info get compacted?

Comment: @BondedDust agree with your title suggestion :)  the columns will be in a character vector supplied, but they'll have to be extracted somehow so something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800161/how-to-find-the-top-n-values-by-group-or-within-category-groupwise-in-an-r-dat/14800163#14800163) will not work because that x$mpg is hardcoded..

Comment: Well that's easy. Use "[[" instead of "$". It will accept a character argument.

Comment: @BondedDust ..but not multiple columns at once?  and even if i can rig tapply to provide the unique levels of each column within multiple-column groups, adding the wide columns is a pretty cumbersome process?  i have gotta be missing something obvious here, but i can't figure out what.

Comment: If I knew what was to be done with one column I'm fairly sure I could answer the question. Still can't figure out the rule to be applied to compress 6 lines of data to a value of `1`. Is it just "existence" of any?

Comment: @BondedDust yes, i'm sorry for being unclear..it's just the existence of any.  i've added a second example to hopefully clarify.  thanks so much for offering your time to help me!!  :)

Comment: `aggregate` could be one (ugly) way to go. For your `mtcars` example you could use `aggregate(cbind(am, vs) ~ cyl + gear , data=mtcars, function(i) unique(identity(i)))` and your minimal example you could use `aggregate(d~ a + b, data=y, function(i) unique(identity(i)))`. All you need to do then is `strsplit` the final column. [your column `d` in the first example should be character]

Comment: @user20650 thanks but you are hard-coding the column names? -- i need this run on different data.frame objects where a, b, and d will be different at every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Maybe you can do something along the lines of this: `aggregate(dat[, unique.cols, drop=F] , by=dat[, ordered.cols] , function(i) unique(identity(i)))`.   Of course still needs tweaking.

Comment: @user20650 wow awesome!  this works quite well if the leftover columns are numeric!  if they are character, it should be this:  `aggregate(x[, unique.cols, drop=F] , by=x[, ordered.cols] , function(i) as.character(unique(i)))`  could you add this as an answer so i can +1?  thanks!

Comment: @Anthony Damico.  You could use `cSplit ` along with the `aggregate` showed by user20650. For the first case: `cSplit(aggregate(x[, unique.cols, drop=F] , by=x[, ordered.cols] , function(i) paste(sort(unique(i)), collapse=",")), c("am", "vs"), "wide", sep=",")[order(cyl)]` and for second `cSplit(aggregate(y[, unique.cols, drop=F] , by=y[, ordered.cols] , function(i) paste(sort(unique(i)), collapse=",")), "d", "wide", sep=",")[order(a)]`. Here I used `sort`.

Comment: @akrun this is fantastic!  could you make this an answer?  is cSplit part of some package?  i searched around and only found it here: https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733

Comment: @Anthony Damico, I will modify my deleted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for my purposes, this solution seems to work well:

```
aggregate( x[ , unique.cols ] , by = x[ , ordered.cols ] , function( w ) paste( sort( unique( w ) ) , collapse = "," ) )

aggregate( y[ , unique.cols ] , by = y[ , ordered.cols ] , function( w ) paste( sort( unique( w ) ) , collapse = "," ) )
```

sometimes (i am not sure why, but i think it's a factor-coercion issue) `nrow( unique( x[ , ordered.cols ] ) )` does not equal the `nrow` of the output of the above commands.  in those cases, this workaround seems to do the trick:

```
halfway <- aggregate( x[ , unique.cols ] , by = list( apply( x[ , ordered.cols ] , 1 , paste , collapse = "" ) ) , function( w ) paste( sort( unique( w ) ) , collapse = "," )  )

cbind( unique( x[ , ordered.cols ] ) , halfway[ , -1 ] )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)

reshapeMyData <- function(x, unique.cols, ordered.cols, NA_class="integer") {
  DT <- as.data.table(x)

  unique.values <- lapply(DT[, unique.cols, with=FALSE], unique)

  ## If your NA is of the wrong class, it can potentially throw an error, 
  ##    depending on when it first shows up.  It is better to be explicit about the expected class
  NA.classed <- as(NA, NA_class)

  ###  -- This is all one line.. it iterates over the unique combinations of ordered.cols values
  DT[, {browser(expr=FALSE)
    ## These three functions shape the data as needed
    setDT(as.list(unlist(
      ## This mapply call checks if each value is in the given group
      mapply(function(v, C) {ifelse(v %in% C, v, NA.classed)}, v=unique.values, C=.SD, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
    )))
  }
  , keyby=ordered.cols, .SDcols=unique.cols]

} ## // end function reshapeMyData
```

#### OUTPUT

```
reshapeMyData(x, unique.cols, ordered.cols)

   cyl gear am1 am2 vs1 vs2
1:   4    3  NA   0  NA   1
2:   4    4   1   0  NA   1
3:   4    5   1  NA   0   1
4:   6    3  NA   0  NA   1
5:   6    4   1   0   0   1
6:   6    5   1  NA   0  NA
7:   8    3  NA   0   0  NA
8:   8    5   1  NA   0  NA

reshapeMyData(y, "d", c("a", "b"), NA_class="character")

   a b d1 d2 d3
1: 1 1  z  y NA
2: 1 2 NA NA  x
3: 2 2 NA NA  x
```

Comment: thank you!  this is pretty genius.  is there an easy way to condense/left align the columns? (in my second example, the two `x`s are in d1 and the column d3 doesn't exist)