# Conditionally selecting last N values within a group by another column using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

This question is similar to selecting the top N values within a group by column [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644994/selecting-top-n-values-within-a-group-in-a-column-using-r).

However, I want to select the last N values by group, with N depending on the value of a corresponding count column. The count represents the number of occurrences of a specific name. If count >3, I only want the last three entries but if it is less than 3, I only want the last entry.

```
# Sample data
df <- data.frame(Name = c("x","x","x","x","y","y","y","z","z"), Value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))

# Obtain count for each name
count <- df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(Count = n_distinct(Value))

# Merge dataframe with count
merge(df, count, by=c("Name"))

# Delete the first entry for x and the first entry for z

# Desired output
data.frame(Name = c("x","x","x","y","y","y","z"), Value = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,9))
```

Comment: you should include `library(dplyr)` and tag your question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, split the `df` by `df$Name` first. Then, for each subgroup, check number of rows and extract last 3 or last 1 row conditionally.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$Name), function(a)
    a[tail(sequence(NROW(a)), c(3,1)[(NROW(a) < 3) + 1]),]))
```

Or

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$Name), function(a)
    a[tail(sequence(NROW(a)), ifelse(NROW(a) < 3, 1, 3)),]))
#    Name Value
#x.2    x     2
#x.3    x     3
#x.4    x     4
#y.5    y     5
#y.6    y     6
#y.7    y     7
#z      z     9
```

For three conditional values

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$Name), function(a)
      a[tail(sequence(NROW(a)), ifelse(NROW(a) >= 6, 6, ifelse(NROW(a) >= 3, 3, 1))),]))
```

Comment: Thank you @d.b! Is there a way to extend this to split it into three different subgroups? I imagine it would have c(6,3,1) (if a count of 6 were my next break point) but I can't really figure out the NROW input

Comment: this looks good but for some reason, I'm not getting the expected output. If I have 

`df <- data.frame(Name = c("x","x","x","x","y","y","y","z","z","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"), Value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7))`  then my expected output is `data.frame(Name = c("x","x","x","y","y","y","z","a","a","a","a","a","a"), Value = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,9,2,3,4,5,6,7))` 

However, instead I get `data.frame(Name = c("a","a","a","x","x","x","y","y","y","z"), Value = c(5,6,7,2,3,4,5,6,7,9))`

Comment: @Anna, try `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$Name), function(a) a[tail(sequence(NROW(a)), ifelse(NROW(a) >= 6, 6, ifelse(NROW(a) >= 3, 3, 1))),]))`

Answer (score 4):

Another dplyrish way:

```
df %>% group_by(Name) %>% slice(tail(row_number(), 
  if (n_distinct(Value) < 3) 1 else 3
))

# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   Name [3]
    Name Value
  <fctr> <dbl>
1      x     2
2      x     3
3      x     4
4      y     5
5      y     6
6      y     7
7      z     9
```

The analogue in data.table is...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, tail(.SD, if (uniqueN(Value) < 3) 1 else 3), by=Name]
```

The closest thing in base R is...

```
with(df, {
  len = tapply(Value, Name, FUN = length)
  nv  = tapply(Value, Name, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))
  df[ sequence(len) > rep(nv - ifelse(nv < 3, 1, 3), len), ]
})
```

... which is way more difficult to come up with than it should be.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 It assumes the OP has it sorted as they wish already, since they just ask for "the last N values by group".

Comment: OK, then this is definitely the best solution.

Comment: Thanks :) Conditional on the need for sorting, I agree that yours is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  split(.$Name) %>%
  map_df(~ if (n_distinct(.x) >= 3) tail(.x, 3) else tail(.x, 1))
```

Which gives:

```
#  Name Value
#1    x     2
#2    x     3
#3    x     4
#4    y     5
#5    y     6
#6    y     7
#7    z     9
```

Comment: This is starting to get esoteric... I like it though

Comment: Could use an `n_distinct` if OP's code is to be believed.

Comment: @Frank Oh, yes. I thought it was not an issue from OP's comment:  *Also, the values are all unique so no need to worry about ties but I appreciate the thoroughness!*

Answer (score 2):

If you're already using dplyr, the natural approach is:

```
library(dplyr)

# Sample data
df <- data.frame(Name = c("x","x","x","x","y","y","y","z","z"), 
                 Value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))

df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(Count = n_distinct(Value),
         Rank = dense_rank(desc(Value))) %>% 
  filter((Count>= 3 & Rank <= 3) | (Rank==1)) %>%
  select(-c(Count,Rank))
```

There's no need for a `merge` since you are just counting and ranking on groups defined by Name.  Then, you apply a filter on your count and rank requirements, and (optionally, for clean-up) drop the counts and ranks.

Comment: See `?ranking` for your ranking options -- your question didn't make it entirely clear how you would break ties.

Comment: Thank you @C8H10N4O2! How would I extend this to a filter by three different groups? For example, if I wanted to break by 6, 3, or 1 count, where I take the "floor" of the count. Also, the values are all unique so no need to worry about ties but I appreciate the thoroughness!

Comment: @Anna you just need to figure out how to write your selection as a logical statement and then put it inside `filter()`.  Also, note that this answer will rank your data by Value, and Frank's just takes the last N rows by group.  So if you are confident that your dataset is already sorted, you should accept Frank's answer.