# select top n values by group with n depending on other value in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, top-n

I'm quite new to r and coding in general. Your help would be highly appreciated :)

I'm trying to select the top n values by group with n depending on an other value (in the following called `factor`) from my data frame. Then, the selected values shoud be summarised by group to calculate the mean (`d100`). My goal is to get one value for `d100` per group.

(Background: In forestry there is an indicator called *d100* which is the mean diameter of the 100 thickest trees per hectare. If the size of the sampling area is smaller than 1 ha you need to select accordingly fewer trees to calculate d100. That's what the *factor* is for.)

First I tried to put the `factor` inside my dataframe as an own column. Then I thought maybe it would help to have something like a "lookup-table", because R said, that n must be a single number. But I don't know how to create a lookup-function. (See last part of the sample code.) Or maybe summarising `df$factor` before using it would do the trick?

**Sample data:**

(I indicated expressions where I'm not sure how to code them in R like this: 'I dont know how')

```
# creating sample data
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(group = c(rep(1, each = 5), rep(2, each = 8), rep(3, each = 10)),
                 BHD = c(rnorm(23, mean = 30, sd = 5)),
                 factor = c(rep(pi*(15/100)^2, each = 5), rep(pi*(20/100)^2, each = 8), rep(pi*(25/100)^2, each = 10))
                )

# group by ID, then select top_n values of df$BHD with n depending on value of df$factor
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  slice_max(
    BHD, 
    n = 100*df$factor, 
    with_ties = F) %>% 
  summarise(d100 = mean('sliced values per group'))

# other thought: having a "lookup-table" for the factor like this:
lt <- data.frame(group = c(1, 2, 3),
                 factor = c(pi*(15/100)^2, pi*(20/100)^2, pi*(25/100)^2))

# then
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  slice_max(
    BHD, 
    n = 100*lt$factor 'where lt$group == df$group', 
    with_ties = F) %>% 
  summarise(d100 = mean('sliced values per group'))
```

I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422003/conditionally-selecting-last-n-values-within-a-group-by-another-column-using-r) answer to a problem which seems similar to mine, but it didn't quite help.

Comment: Would something like this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame/50906379#50906379

Answer (score 0):

Since all the `factor` values are the same within each group, you can select any one `factor` value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  top_n(BHD, n = 100* first(factor))  %>%
  ungroup 

#   group   BHD factor
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     1  25.8 0.0707
# 2     1  24.6 0.0707
# 3     1  27.6 0.0707
# 4     1  28.3 0.0707
# 5     1  29.2 0.0707
# 6     2  28.8 0.126 
# 7     2  39.5 0.126 
# 8     2  23.1 0.126 
# 9     2  27.9 0.126 
#10     2  31.7 0.126 
# … with 13 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution

this will give you the top values for highest `factor` by each `group`

```
    df%>%
      group_by(group)%>%
      slice_max(factor)
    # A tibble: 23 x 3
# Groups:   group [3]
   group   BHD factor
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1  29.9 0.0707
 2     1  31.8 0.0707
 3     1  25.7 0.0707
 4     1  30.7 0.0707
 5     1  23.6 0.0707
 6     2  23.8 0.126 
 7     2  28.3 0.126 
 8     2  30.7 0.126 
 9     2  26.2 0.126 
10     2  31.4 0.126 
# i 13 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

And the you can summarise it to the `d100`

```
 df%>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  slice_max(factor)%>%
  summarise(d100= mean(100*factor)

    # A tibble: 3 x 2
  group  d100
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  7.07
2     2 12.6 
3     3 19.6
```