# Get top k records per group, where k differs by group, in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have two `data.table`s:

1. Values to extract the top `k` from, per `group`.
2. A mapping from `group` to the `k` values to select for that `group`.

[how to find the top N values by group or within category (groupwise) in an R data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14800161/1840471) addresses this question when `k` does not vary by group. How can I do this? Here's sample data and the desired result:

Values:

```
(dt <- data.table(id=1:10,
                  group=c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5))))
#     id group
#  1:  1     1
#  2:  2     1
#  3:  3     1
#  4:  4     1
#  5:  5     1
#  6:  6     2
#  7:  7     2
#  8:  8     2
#  9:  9     2
# 10: 10     2
```

Mapping from `group` to `k`:

```
(group.k <- data.table(group=1:2, 
                       k=2:3))
#    group k
# 1:     1 2
# 2:     2 3
```

Desired `result`, which should include the first two records from `group` 1 and the first three records from `group` 2:

```
(result <- data.table(id=c(1:2, 6:8),
                      group=c(rep(1, 2), rep(2, 3))))
#    id group
# 1:  1     1
# 2:  2     1
# 3:  6     2
# 4:  7     2
# 5:  8     2
```

Applying the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14800271/1840471) to the above-linked question after merging returns this error:

```
merged <- merge(dt, group.k, by="group")
(result <- merged[, head(.SD, k), by=group])
# Error: length(n) == 1L is not TRUE
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166410/show-top-bottom-k-in-each-group-using-data-table/56166489#56166489

Answer (score 5):

I'd rather do it as:

```
dt[group.k, head(.SD, k), by=.EACHI, on="group"]
```

because it's quite clear to see what the intended operation is. `j` can be `.SD[1:k]` of course. Both these expressions will very likely be (further) optimised (for speed) in the next release.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27004002/559784) for a detailed explanation of `by=.EACHI` until we wrap those vignettes.

Answer (score 1):

After merging in the `k` by `group`, a similar approach to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14800271/1840471's solution can be applied, you just need a `unique` to avoid the `length(n)` error:

```
merged <- merge(dt, group.k, by="group")
(result <- merged[, head(.SD, unique(k)), by=group])
#    group id k
# 1:     1  1 2
# 2:     1  2 2
# 3:     2  6 3
# 4:     2  7 3
# 5:     2  8 3
```

Comment: Could also written as `dt[group.k, on = "group"][, .SD[1:k[1L]], by = group]` since `k[1]` will always be the same as `unique(k)`