# Getting top 3 records in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that needs to filtered for only top3 records by the $ amount.

My table looks this

```
PK    Key  Amount 
111   123  $50
111   134  $150
111   154  $550
111   166  $660
111   177  $635
123   145  $245
123   157  $545
123   865  $756
123   875  $765
123   986  $976
```

I need to sort this table to get top 3 Key by $amount.

My End table should be something like this

```
PK    Top3Key 
111   166,177,154
123   986,875,865
```

Thanks for the help.!

Comment: [Perhaps this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800161/how-to-find-the-top-n-values-by-group-or-within-category-groupwise-in-an-r-dat)

Answer (score 0):

If your data is named `df`, do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(PK) %>%
    top_n(3, Amount) %>% 
    summarise(Top3Key = paste(Key, collapse = ','))
```