# Selecting top N rows for each group in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

So i have an example of dataframe below:

```
Index        Country

4.1             USA
2.1             USA
5.2             USA
1.1             Singapore
6.2             Singapore
8.1             Germany
4.5             Italy
7.1             Italy
2.3             Italy
5.9             Italy
8.8             Russia
```

And, I intend to get the **N elements** for each **group** of Country in the dataframe. For example, if **N = 3**, then I will take 3 rows from each group, and if any particular group doesn't have N elements like **Singapore**, then it will just take what is sufficient which is the **two records** with Country label **Singapore**. The same applies for Country label with more than N elements such as Italy, hence it will just take three of it.

For N = 3, the output dataframe would be:

```
Index         Country
4.1             USA
2.1             USA
5.2             USA
1.1             Singapore
6.2             Singapore
8.1             Germany
4.5             Italy
7.1             Italy
2.3             Italy
8.8             Russia
```

I was thinking of something like:

```
aggregate(df, by=list(df$Country), head(df, 3))
```

But it doesn't seemed to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select the top N values by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800161/select-the-top-n-values-by-group)

Comment: The "correct" syntax for aggregate would be `aggregate(df, by = list(df$Country), FUN = head, 3)`, but `aggregate` wants to return 1 row per group, so it adds the additional rows as extra columns, so it's not great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `dplyr`package in the `tidyverse` you can do this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
    ~Index, ~Country
    , 4.1, "USA"
    , 2.1, "USA"
    , 5.2, "USA"
    , 1.1, "Singapore"
    , 6.2, "Singapore"
    , 8.1, "Germany"
    , 4.5, "Italy"
    , 7.1, "Italy"
    , 2.3, "Italy"
    , 5.9, "Italy"
    , 8.8, "Russia"
)

df %>% # take the dataframe
    group_by(Country) %>% # group it by the grouping variable
    slice(1:3) # and pick rows 1 to 3 per group
```

Output:

```
   Index Country  
   <dbl> <chr>    
 1   8.1 Germany  
 2   4.5 Italy    
 3   7.1 Italy    
 4   2.3 Italy    
 5   8.8 Russia   
 6   1.1 Singapore
 7   6.2 Singapore
 8   4.1 USA      
 9   2.1 USA      
10   5.2 USA
```